# Web component <google-map-marker /> not showing

Tags: google-maps, polymer, google-maps-markers

[image]
Using polymer 2.5 & google-map 2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because I changed the `Image` global variable, by writting my own `class Image`. So it cannot draw the marker.